# Как узнать сколько раз действительно скачали ваш файл?

Tags: php, nginx

Всем доброго времени суток, стоит задача создать контроллер реального количества скачиваний файлов не просто обработчик нажатия на onсlick а учитывать отмену скачивания и обрыв соединения если файл хоть теоретически не скачен не изменять количество скачиваний (точнее zip файлов если это важно) (сервер nginx) в результате должна получиться статистика например Пупкин в 19:00 скачал файл Eset.zip, либо Смит пытался скачать файл но не скачал?

Comment: По логам доступа - легко. Сделать похапешную прокладку, которая будет отдавать файл и увеличивать счетчик в базе - тоже не сложно.

Comment: Обычно все запросы логируются в access.log, берите да считайте число нужных строчек там

Comment: `cat access.log | grep file.name | grep ' 200 '`

Comment: @andreymal нужно ещё выбросить 206тые статусы

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Залил реализацию сюда 
https://oleksandrhra@bitbucket.org/oleksandrhra/test.git
кому интересно или необходим пример пользуйтесь.

Answer (score -1):

Нужно считывать с БД **count** и при скачивании файла, UDATE +1 **count**. использовал **RedBeanPHP**. Вот пример:

```
require('connect.php'); 
header("Content-type: text/html; charset=windows-1251");

$array = array("file.pdf", "files/file.pdf", "files/file2.pdf", "files/file3.pdf");

function updateFile($count, $id)
{
    $query = R::getAssoc("UPDATE files SET count = $count WHERE id = '$id'");
    return $query;
}

function getCount($id)
{
    $query  = R::findOne( 'files', 'id = '.$id.'');
    return $query;
}

if ($_GET['id'] == 1){
    $file = $array[1];
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.$array[1].'');      
    $count = getCount(1);
    updateFile($count['count'] + 1, 1);
    readfile($file);
}
else if ($_GET['id'] == 2)
{
    $file = $array[2];
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.$array[2].'');
    $count = getCount(2);
    updateFile($count['count'] + 1, 2);
    readfile($file);
}
else if ($_GET['id'] == 3)
{
    $file = $array[3];
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.$array[3].'');
    $count = getCount(3);
    updateFile($count['count'] + 1, 3);
    readfile($file);
}
else
{
    header('Location: http://site.com/');
    exit;
}
```

в примере несколько файлов..

**connect.php** - подключение к БД

Comment: Вы забыли предупредить, что в плане безопасности этот код — ОГРОМНАЯ ДЫРА!

Comment: ...и вы забыли важную деталь -- счётчик не должен учитывать начавшиеся, но не завершившиеся скачивания. А это как раз самое интересное.